# XML Comments with settings.Settings

Tags: c#, settings

In application im using settings.Settings file for configuration. Is there any way to add comments when using this? One option is to add comments manually to app.config but after adding new config item from settings.Settings view the comments are stripped out.

Is there a way im not aware yet or should i just stop using the settings.Settings view?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809582/documenting-xml-application-settings-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: I have seen that. I want to add comments to the xml file not to the generated documentation!