# Warning: Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member 'Properties.Settings'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, documentation, application-settings

I'm getting two compiler warnings which I want to get rid of it. Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member 'Properties.Settings' and 'Properties.Settings.Default'.

The following code is auto-generated by the Settings Designer of Visual Studio 2013:

```
[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "12.0.0.0")]
public sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

    private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

    public static Settings Default {
        get {
            return defaultInstance;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// My Setting 1
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.SettingsDescriptionAttribute("My Setting 1")]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("0")]
    public double MySetting1 {
        get {
            return ((double)(this["MySetting1"]));
        }
        set {
            this["MySetting1"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to set an XML comment for each setting, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3766930/7556646.

But I don't know how to set the XML comment for the `Settings` class and the static `Default` property?

Editing the auto-generated `Settings.Designer.cs` file is not option for me. The changes are lost every time it's regenerated.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 should create the settings class as `internal` - Has someone manually changed it to `public`?

Comment: I changed it to public. I need to access the settings from another project in my solution.

Comment: Then I suggest you suppress warning 1591 in the project settings (which you'll need to do for each build configuration, e.g. Debug AND Release). Or encapsulate the settings in another (public) class and use that in the other project (which might be a good idea if you want to unit test a consumer of them).

Comment: I know a workaround for the `Settings` class. Settings Designer / View Code. Add XML comments for the `Settings` sealed class and the constructor of it. But for the static `Default` property I don't know a workaround :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't. The only way to overcome this is by setting the access modifier to `internal`, which will remove warning:

[image]

This of course will block access to the properties / resources from another projects in your solution, which might be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that. But I need to access the settings from another project.

Comment: Then the answer is still: *Unfortunately you can't.*

Comment: @Wollmich Make the other solution `InternalsVisibleTo`? This might be a workaround for you.

Comment: I agree with Patrick - using InternalsVisibleTo is preferable to making a settings class public.

Comment: `InternalsVisibleTo` would be an option. Thanks